# How can I remove a file from git using filter-branch making it so I cannot still git grep the contents?

Tags: git, version-control, url-rewriting, git-filter-branch

I've been trying really hard to remove a file with sensitive data from my git repository using this excellent page (among others):
http://help.github.com/removing-sensitive-data/

the primary line being:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached \
    --ignore-unmatch FileWithSecrets.java' HEAD
```

However even when I follow the instructions including the pruning and garbage collection of objects the fact that I've rewritten the history does not seem to remove the file completely.

The point being I can still find the file's contents using git grep:
git grep  $(git rev-list --all)

....and it still shows up.

Am I missing something obvious or non-obvious? Why can I still "git grep" the contents?

I do see that the file is no longer in the changeset when I do a "git show" of the commit where it got added.  But even so I can still grep it - like it's been removed from the branch history but is still floating out there?

Git is fun, cool and amazing but really can shake one's self confidence :)

thanks!!
Brendan

Answer (score 4):

I didn't try this, but since the last argument to git filter-branch is defined as `[--] [<rev-list options>...]` and you're getting the sensitive info from the revs in `git rev-list --all`, this should work:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached \
--ignore-unmatch FileWithSecrets.java' -- --all
                                       ^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Yup, providing HEAD as the argument as the OP did means that only HEAD is rewritten - not even the branch HEAD is pointing to!

Comment: Thanks so much for the answers - pointing out both the HEAD mistake and the --all argument. 

I did try the new command+cleanup and it still did not remove the file from "git grep" results.

I'm wondering if the problem might have something to do with the fact that I have tagged several commits with "git tag" and those are being treated as separate branches.  I tried checking each of these out individually and running the above filter-branch, but I can still grep the 'secret string'.

I did try seeing if I could reproduce with a simple repo, but the commands work.

Comment: @Brendan http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html#_checklist_for_shrinking_a_repository implies that you should add `--tag-name-filter cat` to the filter-branch options.